# Android: How to refresh API data every second

Tags: android, api

I want to refresh API every second. I am calling `AsyncTask` every second for new data. API refreshes, but makes application run slowly.

> Error: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

Answer (score 0):

When calling API use `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);` instead of `execute()`. It may resolve your issue of slowing down memory.